# How to remove padlock (EFS) from files/folders?

Tags: windows-10, encryption

[Image of what I'm seeing is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpwkP.gif)

I'm not 100% sure what I did but I think I might have turned on "Encrypt contents to secure data". option for a file on my Desktop and now all of my files and folders have the padlock icon on it. And I cannot figure out how to get rid of it!

Again, I have no idea what settings I might have included when I checked the "Encrypt contents to secure data" box.

And to make matters worse, by trying to fix the issue myself, I've messed up permissions even further, at least I'm pretty sure i have. Help please? :D

*Note: it says I have Bitlocker *off*.[Bitlocker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94xam.gif)

Comment: The padlock is usually the symbol of BitLocker.

Comment: It says I have Bitlocker off.

Comment: Why not just disable encryption again in the file/folder’s properties?

Comment: It's the Desktop that seems to be encrypted, it shows a padlock under Local Disk C: Regardless, I found someone had the same issue, not sure if it was resolved though! :/ https://superuser.com/questions/1238958/the-desktop-is-encrypting-items-automatically?rq=1

Comment: That icon, while similar to Bitlocker isn't quite the same, I don't think. Other products on your computer may offer encryption features, including your antivirus software. You will need to look through the applications running on your computer and see if any of them offer file encryption, and probably look at your context menu to see if there are any options there you might have accidentally selected once that performs this encryption.

Comment: Further, you've only showed us that Bitlocker is not enabled on your C drive. You have not shown us that Bitlocker is not turned on at all. Bitlocker offers several functions, only one of which is disk encryption.

Comment: I figured it out. What a headache that was though. Bitlocker *was* turned off and I'll be keeping that off. :D My issue was Windows  Encrypting File System (EFS) 
EFS seems to be similar to Bitlocker, but allows encrypting separate files and folders while Bitlocker works with the entire disk supposedly. Regardless, I needed to go to that Desktop icon that showed the EFS padlock on it and simply right-click it and select File ownership -> Personal. That solved the issue. What a headache, I'll have to make sure I don't do that again. :D